# Is there any event callback for producer-broker connection failure like we have for consumer-broker failuer in APache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

Is there any event callback for producer-broker connection failure like we have for consumer-broker failure in APache Kafka like for Consumer we have KafkaRebalanceCallback? Does there exist something similar for the producer since my producer does reconnect if my broker goes down and comes up again or show some kinda log when this happens.

Comment: Kafka producer automatically retries if connection fails with the broker. Try increasing the "retries" count producer properties.  Also beware of the following consequences stated in  official document . ```" If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry, though since we have specified retries as 0 it won't. Enabling retries also opens up the possibility of duplicates"``` - https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: This is for the java library one right. I wanted to. know if there are callbacks available C++ library of librdkafka. Coz for the consumer there seems like there are such callbacks available